# vs2019 & IIS web service & mkcert problem with configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis, configuration, localhost, localserver

I've got a problem with IIS-local. I generated ssl certificate using mkcert, added site to IIS menager and bind it to http and https. Next i add new line with forwarding to hosts file and give IIS permissions to folder with my project. When I try  to visit my site I got message "this site can't be reached". Can someone tell my what else can i do or what I do wrong?

Comment: You might run two reports to gain some insights, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html and https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, are there any other error messages? You can check console or Event viewer. if not you can try to debug the cause use IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.